# Prevent GPG key sharing in VSCode Remote Container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, gnupg, gpg-agent

The following paragraph in the official docs describes how to enable GPG key sharing (from localhost to Remote Container) in VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-gpg-keys).

The instructions (for Linux) simply state that to share GPG keys, install `gnupg2` locally and in the container. But what if I have `gnupg2` installed but I *don't* want to have the keys shared? From what I can tell, VSCode execs post-startup commands within the container where the key sharing gets done, e.g.:

```
Copy /home/karlschriek/.gnupg/pubring.kbx to /home/vscode/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
Copy /home/karlschriek/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg to /home/vscode/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg
...
```

I have not been able to find a setting that will prevent this. It is also, presumably, using the same `gpg-agent` as the localhost. I would like to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Since this behavior does not seem configurable, I would

- move those files in a custom folder (outside ~/.gnupg, and reference it with the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable
- write a remote VSCode starter script which would launch VSCode after a local `export GNUPGHOME=""`

That way, VSCode would search for gnupg files to share in the default ~/.gnupg folder, which is not used in your case.

It is a simple workaround, not an exact solution, but one simple enough to test.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another detail which might help someone: notice that you have to install gnupg locally **and in the container**. I was running into issues with a gnupg command failing during startup and was able to solve it by removing gnupg in my dockerfile (it had been installed automatically).